# Ember - computed property (which is an array) not taking updated value upon adding items to array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Am working on ember app (1.11) and having an issue with computed property not taking updated value when its updated in code . Code as below (have trimmed down, only showing relevant snippet).

Am showing a list of things on UI when iterating through "data" which is a computed property. Then I make a selection from drop down, I am sending a action, triggering that computed property and adding things to that list. When I do this once, I get all the updated list or iteration on UI, but when I do the selection again to increase the list/iteration, the computed property is taking the initial value of list, not the updated one, where I just added one more item, hence not showing correct details.

I am not getting what's going wrong. I could not create a twiddle as well, as its a lot of code and got stuck in error in twiddle.

**Parent Component- ehbs**

```
{{pax-detail list=list}}
```

**Parent Component - js**

```
list: function(){
  return this.get('arr')   //This arr comes from route/controller via query string in url
}.property('arr')
```

**Pax Detail Component- ehbs**

```
{{pax-select action="changed"}}
{{ages ageData=data}}
```

**Pax Detail Component - js**

```
countChanged: '',
actions: {
 changed: function(e){
  this.set('countChanged',e.target.value)
 }
},
data : function(){
  var arr = this.get('list')
  // doing lot to manipulation - constructing arr/object


if(this.get('countChanged')){
  arr.pushObject({}) // basically modifying the initial arr
  return arr
} else {
  return arr
}

}.property('list','countChanged')
```

**Pax Select Component - ehbs**

```
<select>
 <option>0</option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
</select>
```

**Pax Select Component - js**

```
change: function (e) {
   this.sendAction('action',e)
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a computed property here? You shouldn't be using a computed property with the intention of modifying it, or the result and expecting the property to update itself properly going forward.

Comment: So, what should I be using. I thought, computed property is good for this. The idea is to display a list of things, which I am taking from a computed property, as it returns an array. And then when something changes, I need to add item to that array (client side, no page refresh or ajax) and expect the UI to update and show that value.

Comment: Try passing down arr, modify arr, let list update.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I  didn't get that. How will the list update automatically as I add item.

Comment: The list property is listening to 'arr'. So it will update when you modify it. Also, try 'arr.[]'

Comment: Okay. So, I am essentially passing down array only i.e. arr , but its not updating. I also tried arr.[] ,but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I tried, was that whatever I was doing inside "if" condition in computed property "data" , i moved that to action itself. And then I observed it started working. And not to mention, I had to use arr.[], as i understood that in case items of array are changing, i need to listen to all items.
I am still not sure, why is that so but I thought would post this.

Answer (score 1):

Your `arr` doesn't change if your example ( Changes it's content, but the array is the same )

Try next forms
`.property('arr.[]')` or `.property('arr.length')`

or call `.notifyPropertyChange('list')` manually on modifying data.
In fact your example is just
`list: Ember.computed.alias('arr')`

Comment: I understand your point , I had tried using arr.[] , but for some reason it didn't work initially with this code. So, what I tried, was that whatever I was doing inside "if" condition in computed property "data" , i moved that to action itself. And then I observed it started working. And not to mention, I had to use arr.[], as i understood that in case items of array are changing, i need to listen to all items.